# Why would php say two equal things are unequal?

Tags: php

I'm trying to see if a user logging in has entered the right password, which is stored as an md5 hash. when i echo the hash of the password entered, it matches exactly the hash of the one in the database, but it still thinks its false. Heres the code:

```
echo md5($_POST['pass']);

if ($user->match_password($_POST['pass']) == true) {

    ...

} else {

    ...

}
```

it tries to execute the else code above ^

```
class user {

    ...

    var $password;

    ...

    function user($id) {
        global $DB;
        $this->db = new db($DB['host'], $DB['user'], $DB['pass'], $DB['database']);

        $this->user_id = $id;
        $u_result = $this->db->run("select * from users where use_id = " . $this->db->escape($this->user_id));

        ...

        $this->password = $u_reuslt[0]['password'];

            ...
    }

        ...

    function match_password($password) {
        return ($this->password == md5($password));
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the `$u_reuslt` variable is just a typo...?

Comment: @deceze: I suspect you've found the bug. I hope the poster knows of copy/paste!

Comment: yes i believe they did. If you could post that as an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typoed your variables, see comment above.

[E_ALL](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) is your friend. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Check the password field in the DB - if the MD5 password insert correctly, it may be cut because it does not have enough length.

Second, what kind of column is `password`?  It should be a `tinyblob` or `BINARY(32)`, because the results of an MD5 hash can be mangled if stored in a varchar.

Links:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web/Web_Languages/PHP/Q_21578660.html

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?30,16535,16617#msg-16617